# Does blender has a use_pass_roughness or use_pass_specular passes for generating the roughness and specular maps

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, roughness

Similar to diffuse direct, diffuse indirect and glossy etc. Does blender also provide ways to generate roughness and specular or metallic maps? If not how can we render these pbr based value images